# How to filter datatable using between in c#

Tags: c#, filter, datatable

I am using data table with c# and i want to filter data table with between.but when i run my code following exception is thrown "The expression contains unsupported operator 'Between'"

here is the code:

```
string str = "ITEM_ID BETWEEN  " + textEdit1.Text + " AND  " +    textCUS_COA_CODE.Text + " ";

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = this.pAK_ASIADataSet.sp_STOCKS_report;

dt.DefaultView.RowFilter =str;
```

Answer (score 7):

I haven't tried it out, but using `"ITEM_ID >= bla AND ITEM_ID <= bla2"` should work fine.

Comment: dear <= and >= is not applicable for string type data My filter is like this:
string str = "ITEM_ID <= '01-31-0001' AND  ITEM_ID>= '01-33-3333' ;

Answer (score 4):

Looking on the MSDN forums, it seems that `BETWEEN` is not a supported operator for row-filters:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/1220e0f5-4bab-4b53-b8b6-a7a9e8420558/

Can you substitute for an AND:

```
ITEM_ID >= val_oneAND ITEM_ID <= val_two
```

Comment: See more examples on this page: http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/.  +1 for referring to outside reference.

Answer (score 3):

You also can use *LINQ to DataTable*:

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
  .Where(row => {
                    var itemId = row.Field<int>("ITEM_ID");
                    var value1 = int.Parse(textEdit1.Text);
                    var value2 = int.Parse(textCUS_COA_CODE.Text);

                    return itemId >= value1 && itemId <= value2;
                });
```

Comment: LINQ is my best friend too. =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var rows = dt.Select(String.Format("ITEM_ID >= {0} AND ITEM_ID <= {1}", textEdit1.Text, textCUS_COA_CODE.Text))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use between keyword with datatable RowFilter expression, you can use the <= and >= operator in place of between keyword like below:

```
string str = "ITEM_ID <=" + textEdit1.Text + " AND  ITEM_ID>=" +    textCUS_COA_CODE.Text + " ";

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = this.pAK_ASIADataSet.sp_STOCKS_report;

dt.DefaultView.RowFilter =str;
```

Comment: dear <= and >= is not applicable for string type data My filter is like this:
string str = "ITEM_ID <= '01-31-0001' AND  ITEM_ID>= '01-33-3333' ;

Comment: dear <= and >= is not applicable for string type data My filter is like this:
string str = "ITEM_ID <= '01-31-0001' AND  ITEM_ID>= '01-33-3333' ;

Answer (score 1):

Simply use another filter expression as a walk around:

```
String str = String.Format("ITEM_ID >= {0} AND ITEM_ID <= {0}", textEdit1.Text);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = this.pAK_ASIADataSet.sp_STOCKS_report;

dt.DefaultView.RowFilter =str;
```